# Accessing POST data in Facebook canvas app

Tags: php, facebook, forms, post, facebook-canvas

I've got a simple form in my canvas / iframe Facebook app, and I'm trying to pass along the values as POST. Now from reading all about this all over S.O. and FB's latest docs, as I understand it, all data send via a POST form can be accessed on the receiving end from the $_REQUEST object.

I also read on another thread on S.O. that in order for POST forms to work you need to pass along an input named "signed_request" with the value as the current signed_request (I have the signed request working ok otherwise...all login and authentication stuff working fine). This isnt mentioned anywhere in the official FB docs.

So my problem is that all that comes back in the $_REQUEST object is the signed request, and a bunch of other session stuff. My form inputs are nowhere to be found.

The only way I can read them is to set the method of the form to "REQUEST" which isn't even a real form method. But then it takes all of my inputs and sends them as GET args in the URL. Horrible. Here's a sample page from my canvas app with just a form i'm using to try to debug (leaving out all the authentication stuff):

```
<form enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded" method="POST" target="_top" id="my_form" action="https://apps.facebook.com/myfakeapp/form_test.php">
<input type="text" name="test1" value="58" />
<input type="text" name="test2" value="123" />
<input type="text" name="test3" value="434" />
<input type="text" name="test4" value="645" />
<input type="text" name="signed_request" value="<? echo $_REQUEST['signed_request']; ?>">
<input value="Submit Answers" type="submit">
</form>
```

The FB docs are confusing as some of it refers to this beta migration mode they had for older apps dealing with POST requests for canvas apps.

Comment: Dumb question: Have you even tried to use $_POST or skipped it because of what you read? Edit_: If you're in an iFrame, you can just use form_test.php as your action, the target and full app URL shouldn't be required here (at least it works in my Apps running on Fan Pages inside a Tab)

Comment: Yes, believe me I've tried it a million times! There really seems to be a big black hole in FB's documentation for how to handle forms in canvas apps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are combining two separate techniques...the purpose of submitting a form with target=_top and action=apps.facebook.com/xxx is to get Facebook to automatically send the signed_request parameter. If you are sending it yourself, you should use your page's "external" address as the action and leave the target attribute off. By using target=_top, you are reloading the entire framework and sending your form data to Facebook, which of course ignores it.

Comment: Please note that it's not just that simple! you need to actually process the `signed_request` and check if it's not expired yet and the current user is actually the use who submitted the form (not a different user who logged-out the current one from another tab)! I'm not sure if Facebook will refresh all tabs when such a thing happen. But it's worth checking.

Comment: He stated that he had only left out the authentication code for test/debugging purposes, and that he already had signed_request processing worked out beforehand. Since he is passing forward the original signed_request, that part should not change.